# How to count elements with same attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm sure this is an easy one but i'm just not to see the wood for the trees.

I'm having an XML that look like this:

```
   <root>
    <profil>
        <e1 a="2">1</e1>
        <m1 a="3">1</m1>
        <e2 a="4">1</e2>
        <m2 a="5">1</m2>
    </profil>
    <profil>
        <e1 a="5">1</e1>
        <m1 a="3">1</m1>
        <e2 a="4">1</e2>
        <m2 a="4">1</m2>
    </profil>
    <profil>
        <e1 a="7">1</e1>
        <m1 a="7">1</m1>
        <e2 a="4">1</e2>
        <m2 a="2">1</m2>
    </profil>
</root>
```

Now I want to know how many /m*/@a are equal to e*/@a per /profil. So I came up with the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/profil">
                <xsl:element name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(*[contains(name(), 'm') and ./@a = //*[contains(name(),'e')]/@a])"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result is wrong:

```
<root>
    <count>1</count>
    <count>1</count>
    <count>2</count>
</root>
```

It should be

```
<root>
    <count>0</count>
    <count>1</count>
    <count>1</count>
</root>
```

Does anyone has a suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that uses the most appropriate in your case standard XPath function: `starts-with()`. :)

Comment: I've change the title to match better the content of your question. be free to revert to the original if you care about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the XPath with the correct one, which is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(*[substring(name(),1,1)='m' 
      and ./@a = ../*[substring(name(),1,1)='e']/@a])"/>
```

I've used `substring` to match the first attribute character in place of `contains` which matches any character in a string.

Comment: Nice answer - I think `substring` is probably more efficient than `contains` and you beat me to it :) +1

Comment: Perfect and even better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need

```
count(*[contains(name(), 'm') and (@a = parent::*/*[contains(name(),'e')]/@a)])
```

Using this in your XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/profil">
                <xsl:element name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(*[contains(name(), 'm') and (@a = parent::*/*[contains(name(),'e')]/@a)])"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the desired output

```
<root>
  <count>0</count>
  <count>1</count>
  <count>1</count>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks to you also! Works also perfekt as I sad I was just to long looking at that XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

**Use** (with current node any `profil` element):

```
count(*[starts-with(name(),'m')
      and
        @a = ../*[starts-with(name(),'e')]/@a
       ]
      )
```

**And the complete XSLT code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="profil">
  <count>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "count(*[starts-with(name(),'m')
          and
            @a = ../*[starts-with(name(),'e')]/@a
           ]
         )
   "/>
  </count>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <profil>
        <e1 a="2">1</e1>
        <m1 a="3">1</m1>
        <e2 a="4">1</e2>
        <m2 a="5">1</m2>
    </profil>
    <profil>
        <e1 a="5">1</e1>
        <m1 a="3">1</m1>
        <e2 a="4">1</e2>
        <m2 a="4">1</m2>
    </profil>
    <profil>
        <e1 a="7">1</e1>
        <m1 a="7">1</m1>
        <e2 a="4">1</e2>
        <m2 a="2">1</m2>
    </profil>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<count>0</count>
<count>1</count>
<count>1</count>
```