# How to get the number of elements having same attribute in HTML in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a HTML document which contains elements having the same class name.  I could just do an iteration over all the elements in a page and store with elements with a class name in a list. Is there a better way in Watir to get a count of all the HTML elements having the same class name? This question [Count of Elements with same attribute in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397347/how-to-count-elements-with-same-attribute-value) kind of addresses the issue, but I had two queries related to that

1. What if the HTML document is not a strict XHTML document?
2. What happens if different types of HTML elements have the same class?

Sample HTML files could be:

Elements of the same type having same class name

```
<input type="password" class="foo" /> 
<input type="text" class="foo" />
```

Elements of different types having same class name

```
<input type="password" class="foo" /> 
<span class="foo"></span>
<a href='1' class="foo">Text</a>
```

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: added watir-webdriver and also ruby as this might be more of a ruby question than a watir question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using [watir-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver) gem:

1)

HTML

```
<input type="password" class="foo" /> 
<input type="text" class="foo" />
```

Watir

```
browser.elements(:class => "foo").size
# => 2
```

2)

HTML

```
<input type="password" class="foo" /> 
<span class="foo"></span>
<a href='1' class="foo">Text</a>
```

Watir

```
browser.elements(:class => "foo").size
# => 3
```