# How to determine what type of a HTML element is selected in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

This is a follow-up to the [Counting the number of HTML elements having same attribute in Watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433084/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-having-same-attribute-in-html-in-watir) question.

So, suppose I have a HTML element as follows

```
<input type="password" class="foo" /> 
<span class="foo"></span>
<a href='1' class="foo">Text</a>
```

So, I can obtain a collection of all the elements having the same class name by using

```
 elements = browser.elements(:class,"foo")
```

Since, its an collection, I can use the each method to iterate over the collection. While iterating over the collection, I want to determine what type of tag is represented? (Something similar to the nodeName or the tagName method in Javascript). Is there a way we could do this in Watir?

Sample code would be :

```
elements = browser.elements(:class,"foo")
elements.each { |element|
puts element.<Watir_method_similar_to_nodeName_of_JavaScript>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elements.each {|element| puts element.tag_name}
```

Output:

```
input
span
a
```

Comment: Isn't this method present in the watir gem since I was getting the NoMethodError when I ran it in irb. After googling, I found that this method is present in the watir-webdriver gem. Doesn't the watir gem currently support a similar method?

Comment: If you got the error, then it does not support it. :) I use watir-webdriver almost all the time.

Comment: The time to move to watir-webdriver is now. :)